# Difference between "outfit" and "costume"

Tags: word-choice

What is the difference between *outfit* and *costume*? For example, if you don't typically go to clubs, but you buy a certain set of clothes that you think will make you look like a typical club-goer, which does that set of clothing constitute?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A costume is something you put on to make yourself look like something or some one, especially an actor dressing as a character.

An outfit is just a set of clothing that (hopefully) goes well together.

So, clothes you wear to a club are just an outfit, since you are not attempting to portray someone or something else.

Answer (score 2):

If you're dressing up to affect a personality for a party or other celebratory occasion, or if you are an actor playing a role, it's a costume.